# Histogram configuration

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

We have a set of data.
We want the histograms of them and plot them in the logarithm scale. We use the following code:

```
y,binEdges=np.histogram(hist_data,bins=200)
bincenters = 0.8*(binEdges[1:]+binEdges[:-1])
p.plot(bincenters,y,'-')
p.yscale('log', nonposy='clip')
```

The result is:
[image: Figure of bins=200]

However, when I try to increase the bin(i.e. from bins=200 to bins=600), the result is:
[image: Figure of bins=600]]

How is able to keep only the lines and not the whole spectrum of each histogram?

Comment: Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: With 600 bins, are any of the bins empty or contain relatively small values?

Comment: Yes i get 'True' to all of them. But how can I smooth it in another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is that some of the bins are *empty*, so it draws a rectangle that goes from `f(y) -> 0 -> f(y+delta) -> 0 -> f(y+2*delta)`. A common trick to get around this is not to use a sharp cutoff as your bin (we call it a *kernal*). You can use, for example, [Kernel density estimation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation) to "smooth" out the histogram. In this case you place a bunch of gaussians centered at your data points -- the sum is reflective of the underlying probability distribution. You can use scipy to perform the KDE or the nice package [`seaborn`](http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/distplot_options.html) that will do it with the plotting automatically. The picture from the linked seaborn example gives a nice illustration of this:

[image]

To use matplotlib's `hist` without drawing boxes and only using the lines pass in [`histtype="step"`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib.pyplot.hist).

Answer (score 1):

If some of the bins are *empty* you can filter them out with [boolean indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
p.plot(bincenters[y>0],y[y>0],'-')
```